# Sum count algorithm name

Tags: algorithms, summation, recursive-algorithms

I want to find out what this algorithm is called

```
int s(int m, int n) {
    if (m == 1 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n >= m) {
        return s(m, m - 1) + 1;
    } else {
        return s(m - n, n) + s(m, n - 1);
    }
}
```

[image: table]

I think it counts possible sums with limited summands

like s(5,5)=7

1. 1+1+1+1+1
2. 2+1+1+1
3. 2+2+1
4. 3+1+1
5. 3+2
6. 4+1
7. 5

Comment: This algorithm is obviously called `s`. I think what you really want to ask it what the value it computes represents in terms of the values of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: It may also be noted that in the table the value of $m$ increases horizontally, the value of $n$ vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
for (int y = 1; y <= m; y++) {
    for (int x = 1; x <= m; x++) {

        if (x == 1 || y == 1) {
            arr[y][x] = 1
        } else if (x == y) {

            arr[y][x] = arr[y - 1][x] + 1

        } else if (y > x) {
            arr[y][x] = arr[y - 1][x]

        } else if (x > 1 && y > 1) {

            arr[y][x] = arr[y - 1][x] + arr[y][x - y]
        }   

    }

}
```